Woman kills a man inside a cardboard box by plunging scissors/knife into his head
I remember a single scene from that movie which I saw while flipping channels, maybe 10-15 years ago (but not quite sure when).
A woman receives a big box, and tries to open it, but it's difficult to unwrap, so she grows frustrated, and then she takes the scissors, and tries to cut the tape, but still no luck.
Finally, she jabs the scissors into the box, and manages to open it, only to find a naked man inside - and she has plunged the scissors directly into his head, and half of it has sunk into his brain. She then starts screaming.
At that point I flipped the next channel, but this scene impressed itself in my mind, so I want to find that movie and watch it.
I can only guess at the context, but I think the man would have been her boyfriend, who wanted to give her a surprise.

Is this Hollywood movie? Made for TV movie?

I don't really know. As I said, I watched it a long time ago, and only that scene (in isolation).

I'm assuming this is Michael Egan's 1997 short film The Gift, since you're describing the exact plot of the Velvet Underground song by the same name and this film seems to be an adaptation of it. It's a bit hard to find any footage or images from this film, but by the pic on IMDb of a guy hiding in a box, I'm assuming it's faithful to the song. And it seems this song is popular fodder for short films, because there are 2 other adaptations available online here and here.

No doubt you seemingly have the right story here, but if you out on YouTube, you can find a plethora of film shorts with this theme. Seems, as you stated, it is very popular fodder. +1 even if the OP doesn't accept.

Holy CRAP there are a lot of them there. Most of them by film students. Good luck, sashoalm. :)

I think it's called: life in the fast lane, with the original title: there's no fish food in heaven. Made in 1998. 

This looks like a good answer, but could you please elaborate? (I added a link)
